# how can I use my to_json_string method to write the JSON string representation of a list of instances to a file

Tags: python, oop, json-serialization

I have a base class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Base class for all other classes in this module"""
import json


class Base:
    """Base Class

    Args:
        __nb_objects (int): number of instances of class
    """
    __nb_objects = 0

    def __init__(self, id=None):
        """class constructor

        Args:
            id (int, optional): argument value to initialize. Defaults to None.
        """
        if id is not None:
            self.id = id
        else:
            type(self).__nb_objects += 1
            self.id = type(self).__nb_objects

    @staticmethod
    def to_json_string(list_dictionaries):
        """returns the JSON string representation of list_dictionaries

        Args:
            list_dictionaries ([{}]): a list of dictionaries.
        """
        if list_dictionaries is None or len(list_dictionaries) == 0:
            return "[]"

        return json.dumps(list_dictionaries)

    @classmethod
    def save_to_file(cls, list_objs):
        """writes the JSON string representation of list_objs to a file

        Args:
            list_objs (list): list of instances who inherits of Base
        """
        filename = type(list_objs[0]).__name__ + ".json"
        json_file = open(filename, "w")
        if list_objs is None:
            json.dump([], json_file)

        if type(list_objs[0]).__name__ == "Rectangle":
            new_dict = [item.to_dictionary() for item in list_objs]
            json_string = cls.to_json_string(new_dict)
            json.dump(new_dict, json_file)

        json_file.close()
```

and a Child class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Definition of Rectangle"""
from . base import Base


class Rectangle(Base):
    """define a rectangle object

    Args:
        Base (class): Base Class
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, x=0, y=0, id=None):
        """rectangle constructor

        Args:
            width (int): width of rectangle
            height (int): height of rectangle
            x (int, optional): x offset of rectangle. Defaults to 0.
            y (int, optional): y offset of rectangle. Defaults to 0.
            id (int, optional): identifier. Defaults to None.
        """
        super().__init__(id)
        if type(width) is not int:
            raise TypeError('width must be an integer')
        if width < 1:
            raise ValueError('width must be > 0')
        self.width = width

        if type(height) is not int:
            raise TypeError('height must be an integer')
        if height < 1:
            raise ValueError('height must be > 0')
        self.height = height

        if type(x) is not int:
            raise TypeError('x must be an integer')
        if x < 0:
            raise ValueError('x must be >= 0')
        self.x = x


        if type(y) is not int:
            raise TypeError('y must be an integer')
        if y < 0:
            raise ValueError('y must be >= 0')
        self.y = y


        @property
        def width(self):
            """Getter and Setter methods for width"""
            return self.width

        @width.setter
        def width(self, value):
            if type(value) is not int:
                raise TypeError('width must be an integer')
            if value < 1:
                raise ValueError('width must be > 0')
            self.width = value

        @property
        def height(self):
            """Getter and Setter methods for height"""
            return self.height

        @height.setter
        def height(self, value):
            if type(value) is not int:
                raise TypeError('height must be an integer')
            if value < 1:
                raise ValueError('height must be > 0')
            self.height = value

        @property
        def x(self):
            """Getter and Setter methods for x"""
            return self.x

        @x.setter
        def x(self, value):
            if type(value) is not int:
                raise TypeError('x must be an integer')
            if value < 0:
                raise ValueError('x must be >= 0')
            self.x = value

        @property
        def y(self):
            """Getter and Setter methods for y"""
            return self.y

        @y.setter
        def y(self, value):
            if type(value) is not int:
                raise TypeError('y must be an integer')
            if value < 0:
                raise ValueError('y must be >= 0')
            self.y = value

    def area(self):
        """returns the area value of the Rectangle instance"""
        return self.width * self.height

    def display(self):
        """prints in stdout the Rectangle instance with the character #"""
        print(('\n' * self.y) + '\n'
              .join(' ' * self.x + '#' * self.width
                    for _ in range(self.height)))

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns an informal string representation a Rectangle object"""
        return '[Rectangle] ({}) {}/{} - {}/{}'\
            .format(self.id, self.x, self.y,
                    self.width, self.height)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """update the instance attributes"""
        if len(kwargs):
            if 'height' in kwargs:
                self.height = kwargs['height']
            if 'width' in kwargs:
                self.width = kwargs['width']
            if 'x' in kwargs:
                self.x = kwargs['x']
            if 'y' in kwargs:
                self.y = kwargs['y']
            if 'id' in kwargs:
                self.id = kwargs['id']

        else:
            try:
                self.id = args[0]
                self.width = args[1]
                self.height = args[2]
                self.x = args[3]
                self.y = args[4]
            except IndexError:
                pass

    def to_dictionary(self):
        """returns the dictionary representation of a Rectangle"""
        return self.__dict__
```

and here is the main file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
""" 15-main """
from models.rectangle import Rectangle

if __name__ == "__main__":

    r1 = Rectangle(10, 7, 2, 8)
    r2 = Rectangle(2, 4)
    Rectangle.save_to_file([r1, r2])

    with open("Rectangle.json", "r") as file:
        print(file.read())
```

The task is to use the "**to_json_string**" method (which returns a json string of a list of dictionaries of instance attributes) in Base to write the function "**save_to_file**" that saves a list of dictionaries of instance attributes that inherits from base

**to_json_string** accepts a list of dictionaries and **save_to_file** accepts a list of instances of the child class Recangle(list_objs), so in order to pass list_objs to **to_json_string**, I have to create a list of dictionaries of instance attributes, which is what this line does:

```
new_dict = [item.to_dictionary() for item in list_objs]
```

but when I pass this list to **to_json_string** and try to dump it in the file Rectangle.json, with the lines

```
new_dict = [item.to_dictionary() for item in list_objs]
            json_string = cls.to_json_string(new_dict)
            json.dump(json_string, json_file)
```

I get an output like:

```
"[{\"id\": 1, \"width\": 10, \"height\": 7, \"x\": 2, \"y\": 8}, {\"id\": 2, \"width\": 2, \"height\": 4, \"x\": 0, \"y\": 0}]"
```

But when dump list to the file, I get the list of dictionaries in the file like:

```
[{"id": 1, "width": 10, "height": 7, "x": 2, "y": 8}, {"id": 2, "width": 2, "height": 4, "x": 0, "y": 0}]
```

So why do I get the output with the double quotes and how can I use the **to_json_string** to get the correct output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you try to json dump *twice*, once in `to_json_string` and then again with the result, so you get a string, and then write that string as the entire content (the resulting string is valid json, however dubiously)

```py
>>> d = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> print(json.dumps(json.dumps(d)))
"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
>>> print(json.dumps(d))
{"foo": "bar"}
```

You could remove one `.dump` instance, make the dump stringifying optional, set some flag, check for a string before re-`.dump`-ing, or whatever other logic you like instead!

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about dumping twice, writing to json_file rather than dumping also fixed the issue

Comment: @Marlon excellent! if this [or other Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17472207/marlon?tab=questions) solve your Question, please mark them as the Answer with the check to their left to gain reputation and help the community!